# JavaScript Loop Output

Tags: javascript, loops, screen, output

all. I'm new to JavaScript, so hopefully this is a pretty easy question for you all. But I absolutely, for the life of me, cannot figure out how to do this! I'm creating a times table program, and I need the output to look something like this:

5 x 1 = 5 
5 x 2 = 10 
5 x 3 = 15 
...

...and so on. However, whenever it outputs to the screen, it only displays the LAST output from the loop. So it will show "5 x 12 = 60". I need it to show each individual output everytime the program goes through the loop. How would I go about doing this?

Much thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- 
        Input
            User clicks the "Compute Table" button.
        Processing
            The computer creates a times table based on the users' input.
        Output
            Outputs the table to the user.
        -->


<title>Times Table</title>
<script>
    function computeTable() {

    // Declaring some variables and pulling the integer from the HTML form. Nothing to see here.
    var integer = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
    var i = 1;

    // Running the loop and doing all the arithmetic
    while (i < 12) {
        i++;
    }

    // This line displays the output to the user
    var output = document.getElementById('outputdiv');
    output.innerHTML = integer + " x " + i + " = " + (integer * i);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Times Table</h1>

Please enter a positive integer: <input type="text" id="input">
<button type="button" onclick="computeTable()">Compute Table</button>
<hr>
<div id="outputdiv" style="font-weight:bold"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your div each time the variable is incremented.

```
var output = document.getElementById('outputdiv');
while (i < 12) {
    output.innerHTML = integer + " x " + i + " = " + (integer * i);
    i++;
}
```

Though I think it will update your result very quickly and you may not be able to see each result.  Maybe you want something like this?

```
var output = document.getElementById('outputdiv');
var html;
if (output.innerHTML.length != 0) {
    output.innerHTML = "";
}
while (i < 12) {
    html = output.innerHTML;
    html += (i > 1 ? ", " : "") + integer + " x " + i + " = " + (integer * i);
    output.innerHTML = html;
    i++;
}
```

Which should give you something like `result_1, result_2, result_3, //etc.`

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qzD3V/1/).  Also, as **Johnannes** pointed out in his answer and comment, updating the innerHTML can be done directly `output.innerHTML += value;`

Comment: Instead of reading innerHTML, appending to it and writing back, you could just append to innerHTML directly - see my answer.

Comment: @JohannesH. I agree, more efficient, I wrote it explicitly to better illustrate the technique.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

1) You're only outputting once - so no matter what you do, there is only one line. Sound's reasonable, right?

2) Even if you did output multiple times, `output.innerHTML = "..."` would override any previous assignements. 'cause it's an assignement, it doesn't APPEND.

So the solution is APPENDING INSIDE the loop:

```
var i = 1;
while ( i < 12 ) {
    output.innerHTML += integer + " x " + i + " = " + (integer * i) + "<br>";
    i++;
}
```

This can be done in a shorter way, using a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 1 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
    output.innerHTML += integer + " x " + i + " = " + (integer * i) + "<br>";    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU! I didn't know it was something so simple! I'll keep working. Someday I'll get to be awesome at programming like you all!

Comment: It's really just a matter of practice, so I'm certain you will get better :D